# Two non-clustered index vs one clustered and one non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, logging, database-performance

I have a log table(with 16 columns) which stores the transaction related data. We mostly perform search operations only on two columns. Should I create one clustered index and one non-clustered index or should I create two non-clustered index. We want to improve our search performance.

Note : As this is a transaction log. We get half million records daily.

Comment: If you are going to be querying this table you will want to have a clustered index. Otherwise your table is a heap and searching can get horribly slow pretty easily. As to the specifics of your indexes nobody can really say what is right here because we have no idea what your table definition is or how you go about querying it.

Comment: In addition, I would add an index, test the retrieval time of your query, add another one and so on until your performance is optimal.  This way you can find out the right number and type of indexes to add.

Comment: @SeanLange currently there is a identity column (Id) which is primary key for this table. So we have clustered indexing on it. But our search mainly deals with “customerId” and “FI” columns. Shall we move clustered index to one of these columns.

Comment: Maybe, possibly, probably...any suggestion from me would be guess work at best without more information about the table.

Comment: Every question about perfomance has 1 answer - "it depends". No one knows your schema, the patterns of access, the patterns of insert/update/delete. There are many discussions about advantages and disadvantages of a heap. There are many discussions about choosing the best clustered index. Those are the things you should address first. After that you experiment and evaluate the results. Remember - nothing is free. Indexes add overhead to DML statements.